# Torch multiprocessing refusing to serialize non-leaf tensor

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, torch

My goal is to compute an adversarial attack on batched data. Unfortunately, this attack cannot be easily implemented to work on batches, so I tried working with the `torch.multiprocessing` package, which is just a wrapper of python's multiprocessing package.

This is the code:

```
with Pool(1) as p:
    results = p.map(attack_f, list(zip(X_split,[i for i in range(len(X_split))])))
    results.sort(key=lambda x : x[1])
    results = [r[0] for r in results]
    results = [a for b in results for a in b]

for return_dict_sparse_fool in results:
    model_pred_sparse_fool = get_prediction(net, X_adv_sparse_fool, "non_prob")
```

This works the first time the pool is created and the processes finish. The second time the processes are spawned, the following error message appears:

`Cowardly refusing to serialize non-leaf tensor which requires_grad, since autograd does not support crossing process boundaries.  If you just want to transfer the data, call detach() on the tensor before serializing (e.g., putting it on the queue).`

I then tried to identify the source of the problem and just tried to `deepcopy` the network. I changed the last line to

`model_pred_sparse_fool = get_prediction(deepcopy(net), X_adv_sparse_fool, "non_prob")`

and it works. But I would like to understand what the issue is here. Unfortunately, I don't have much experience in PyTorch.